# Is there a way to insert children at specific position?

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller, javafx-8, fxml, vbox

thats a part of my fxml:

```
<VBox>
  <children>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

I want to add a new child to vBox. But i want to add it at a specific position, for example between the two buttons "at position 2".

Comment: Do you mean you're adding it in the controller (i.e. with Java code)?

Comment: yes, like 
vbox.getChildren().add(myNewButton);

Comment: but i want to say something like "add(component, position);"

Comment: `getChildren()` just returns a list. You can use any methods defined for a regular list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child list of a pane is an `ObservableList`, which is just a subinterface of a plain old `java.util.List`. So you have access to all the usual [list methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-). Assuming you have a reference to the `VBox` in your controller, call it `vbox`, you can just do

```
vbox.getChildren().add(1, myNewButton);
```